# Image Transformation causes error 503

Tags: image-transforms, craft4, plugin-imager

I have too many images on a overview page, and it kills the server which creates a error 503.

- I converted all source images to less than 1MB, but it still crashes the server. (Using Imager X on craft 4).
- It was working under craft 3 but craft 4 seems to be not as resourceful, idk and yeah my code isn't great.
- php execution time is 300 seconds

1. Is there a way to see at which image the server goes down?
2. Is there any way to write the image macro causing this more efficiently?

   ```
   {% macro portfolioListing(handleParam, ratioRaram) %}
   {% set image = handleParam %}
   {% import _self as macro %}
   {% if handleParam | length %}
       {% if handleParam.extension == 'svg' %}
           {{ svg(image) }}
       {% else %}
       {% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(image, 
               [{ width: 170 }, { width: 980 },{ width: 1065 }],
               { jpegQuality: 75, ratio: ratioRaram, allowUpscale: false },
               { filenamePattern: macro.imageNaming(image) | kebab ~ '-' ~ '_{fullname|shorthash}.{extension}' }) 
           %}

           <img
               data-sizes="auto"
               src="{{ craft.imager.placeholder() }}"
               data-srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedImages) }}"
               alt="{{ macro.imageNaming(image) }}"
               class="lazyload{{ image.dropShadow ? ' dropShadow' : '' }}"
               data-majorImg="{{transformedImages[3].url}}"
           />
       {% endif %}

   {% endif %}

   {% endmacro %}
   ```

Not sure how to go about this right now.

Comment: Have you considered to use Craft's native transforms?